# Connecting to localhost from Docker (Java Application using localstack for mocking AWS)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, localstack

I am using localstack to mock AWS resources locally. This works fine when I run my application from the IDE. I have a dockerfile which contains the following (1338 is the port this app would run on)

```
ADD target/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
```

and I have a script to run which is

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e # Stop on errors

mvn clean package

docker build -t myapp .

docker run -it --name myapp -p 1338:1338 --rm myapp:latest
```

So when I run I get the error

```
Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to localhost:4575 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Comment: If the `localstack` is not in the docker image `myapp:latest`, then you will not able to connect to localstack in the docker container. I think you have 2 choice, 1, install/configure localstack inside the docker image myapp. 2, `docker run` with parameter `--network host`.

Comment: 2nd option worked, add as an answer and i will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you're running localstack on your host OS, that's why the `myapp` unable to reach it.
To solve your issue, you need adjust your `docker run` instruction by adding parameter `--network host`.